# Scrapy - Stopping crawler when duplicate item encountered

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

There are lots of websites I have to hard code page follow (incrementing page number after crawling items) and some of those websites return to page 1 after the last page. For example if a website has 25 pages of items, sending a request to the 26th page yields a response of first page.

At that point duplicate filter of Scrapy works fine and doesn't scrape items, but the crawler keeps running. Is there any way to stop crawling process when duplicate filter is triggered like this?

I don't want to hardcode the page number like this since it can change over time.

```
if self.page < 25:
    yield scrapy.Request(...)
```

Comment: Just set a global variable and have your callbacks return early

Comment: @pguardiario but setting a global variable to track what?

Comment: To track when it should stop.

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure your request not to be filtered out by the duplicate filter (add `dont_filter=True` to the request constructor)
2. Use the request callback to stop the crawler (`raise scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider`) when `response.url` is unexpectedly the URL of the first page

Comment: Good solution, but that won't work in this case because the url of the page is keep incrementing, but the response belongs to page 1.

Comment: Usually you can send in `request.meta` the expected page, extract the current page from the `response`, and when they do not match assume you are at step #2 from my answer.